# Use timer on Windows Phone application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7.1

How to create a timer for c# windows phone 7?
I already find a timer, but it was for normal c#, and on C# for windows phone we can´t use system.Timers!I want to play the video just from 5000ms.

This is my code:

using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("xml_file.xml", FileMode.Open);

```
            XElement xml = XElement.Load(isoFileStream);

                    foreach (XElement node2 in xml.Element("graphics").Elements("file"))
                    {



                        string url_graficos = node2.Element("fileurl").Value;

                        string[] array = url_graficos.Split('/');
                        string[,] resultadosImage = { { node2.Element("fileurl").Value, node2.Element("playtime").Value, node2.Element("transition").Value } };

                        mediaSound.Play();
                        mediaSound.Stop();
```

Answer (score 3):

The class you are looking for is a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickyt/archive/2010/08/13/windows-phone-applications-timing-and-threading.aspx) is a good tutorial on how to use it.

Hope this helps you.